Does Windows 11 have directory shortcuts in the file dialogs?
I recently migrated from Windows 10 to Windows 11
Windows 10 had shortcuts for directories you could set. These shortcuts would appear in File/Open dialogs and I believe in the File Explorer as well.
I can't find that in Windows 11.
Does that feature still exist?

Do you mean libraries, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/client-tools/windows-libraries ? The standard folders Documents, Downloads, Music, Pictures and Videos? You can also add or remove folders from This PC: https://www.elevenforum.com/t/add-or-remove-folders-under-this-pc-in-file-explorer-in-windows-11.7122/

I don't understand your comment.
I want folders of my choosing to appear as "Quick Links" in Explorer and to appear in File Open/Save dialogs.
